# map if condition and append to list

Tags: python, dictionary, if-statement, append

Is there an easy way to code the following example by using map function? If not, how could be done by using list comprehension?

```
lst1=['a','b','c']
lst2=['a','b','c','d']

l=[]
for iteml1 in lst1:
        if iteml1 in lst2:
            l.append((lst2.index(iteml1),iteml1))
```

l is a vector that contains the index of lst1 element in lst2 list and lst2 element. output:

```
l
Out[1]: [(0,'a'),(1,'b'),(2,'c')]
```

Comment: it already fixed ;), thnx for the correction.

Comment: The challenge is solve it by using map, list comprehension is widely solved in this forum, it make no sense to score the question in a negative way...

Comment: Do it using `map` and LC only makes the question sound like a coding challenge rather than an actual problem. Instead you should ask what are some better ways to do it in terms of time, readability, best practices etc

Comment: I agree, Im gonna have it in mind the next time. thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on the size of your lists, you may want to build a dict mapping the items in `lst1` to their indices to *avoid* repeated *O*(n) `list.index` lookups and *O*(n) membership checks for each item:

```
dct = dict((k, v) for v, k in enumerate(lst1))
l =  [(dct[x], x) for x in lst1 if x in dct]
print(l)
# [(0, 'a'), (1, 'b'), (2, 'c')]
```

Membership check and `__getitem__` for dicts are both done in constant time.

Answer (score 2):

```
l = [(lst2.index(item), item) for item in lst1 if item in lst2]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create a dictionary from `lst2` that maps its items to their indices and then use it to obtain the expected output. This will be `O(N)`.

```
>>> indices = {x: i for i, x in enumerate(lst2)}    
>>> [(indices[item], item) for item in lst1 if item in indices]
[(0, 'a'), (1, 'b'), (2, 'c')]
```

Another option will be to get a set containing intersection of both lists and then loop over `lst2` and do a lookup in that set:

```
>>> s = set(lst2).intersection(lst1)    
>>> [(i, x) for i, x in enumerate(lst2) if x in s]
[(0, 'a'), (1, 'b'), (2, 'c')]
```

Answer (score 2):

Using map :

```
dict(map(lambda x: (lst2.index(x), x), lst1))
```

output

```
{0: 'a', 1: 'b', 2: 'c'}
```

for output list of dict :

```
result.items()
```